# in web application project, how to make the source code folder inaccessible?

Tags: web-applications

I have a web application project and I have put my source code in a folder called "source". Now when I run the application I am able to see contents of "source" folder (it lists the code files) by appending the folder name to the url "/source" in IE.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: If your project is written in a language that runs on the server (PHP, for example), then this probably isn't an issue because the browser only sees the resulting HTML.

What language are you writing your project in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have directory browsing on....

Tell IIS not to allow directory browsing by unchecking it under the virtual directory tab for the application in IIS.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, and most fool-proof, answer would be to put the source-code folder outside of the web root:

```
-var-+-www-+- htdocs
        |      |
        |      +- images
        |      |
        |      +- javascript
        |      |
        |      +- css
        |      |
        |      +- ...and so on...
        |
        +- source code
        |
        +- php includes
        |
        +- ...and so on...
```

The idea is that only the htdocs directory, and sub-directories, should be visible/accessible to web-browsers; the other directories should not be accessible at all, except via ftp (or the administration interface provided by your web host).

Comment: +1 The technique of including files in your code that are out of the wwwroot or htdocs folder is the most simple and effective way to hide your code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is IIS you can turn off directory browsing.  Open the IIS manager and navigate to your application root.  Expand the application root and right-click on the Source directory and choose Properties.  In the Directory tab ensure that the Directory Browsing checkbox is left unchecked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your code online would be the obvious answer.

But you could restrict access with the web.config

```
<location path="Source">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
            <deny roles="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```